# The getButton method is returning undefined

Tags: fine-uploader

attempting to call `$(this).fineUploader("getButton", id);` in the submit event handler and getting `undefined` as a result.

I assume the buttons are being tracked since access to the button is available within the validate and upload events.  However, I really would like to know which button was clicked during the submit event so I can set parameters for the specific file upload.  The validate event has no file id present to associate specific parameters

**In Response to Comments, additional information:**

Fineuploader Version 4.1.1

I have tried the scenario in many configurations and getButton method call never works in the submit handler

```
myfineuploader.on('submit', function(event, id, name) {
  var button = $(this).fineUploader('getButton', id);
  console.log(button);  // Button always shows undefined here
}
```

The buttons are defined as spans outside of the template, setup like this in the config:

```
button: $("#button1"),
extraButtons: [
   {
      element: $("#button2")
   }
]
```

Comment: Please tell us which version of fine Uploader you are using and include all of your client side Fine Uploader related code.  It is important to understand the context of your call in order to assist you best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button is not associated with the file until after the submit event callback has completed.  This was done to ensure that mappings were created only for files that passed all possible validation steps, since it is possible to reject a file in your "submit" handler as well.  After some thought, it may be best to create this button to file mapping as soon as we have created an ID for this file internally. I've created an [item in our issue tracker](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/1116) to deal with this.

If you move your logic into a ["submitted" event handler](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#submitted) instead, you should be good to go.

Comment: I cannot move my logic into the "submitted" event handler as it's too late in the process to keep the uploader from submitting!  The whole purpose in knowing which button is pressed is so I can make contextual decisions on the validity of the upload.

Comment: What sort of decisions are you attempting to make, specifically?